# Call blocking for a particular time period in Android

Tags: java, android, timer, phone-call

I am developing an app which will block all call for particular time period, but i am getting some problem while executing this app, its not blocking any calls. so please tell me what is the problem in my code, it is blocking calls but not for perticular time.. i am posting my code.

```
public class Pervasive_2Activity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */

   private PhoneCallReceiver1 action;
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
int hour1;
int minutes1;
int hour2;
int minutes2;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    action= new PhoneCallReceiver1();
    Date dt = new Date();
     hours = dt.getHours();
     minutes = dt.getMinutes();
     seconds = dt.getSeconds();

    Button OK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.widget39);

    OK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
    TimePicker tp1 = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
     hour1 = tp1.getCurrentHour();
     minutes1 =tp1.getCurrentMinute();
     TimePicker tp2 = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker2);
     hour2 = tp2.getCurrentHour();
     minutes2 =tp2.getCurrentMinute();
    }
    });



    if((hours>hour1 && hours<hour2)&& (minutes>minutes1 && minutes<minutes2))
 {
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
 Intent intent = this.getIntent();

action.onReceive(context, intent);
 }
   }
  }
```

class--2

```
   public class PhoneCallReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context = null;
private static final String TAG = "Phone call";
private ITelephony telephonyService;

    @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Receving....");
   TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
     try {
  Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
  Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
   m.setAccessible(true);
   telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
 //  telephonyService.silenceRinger();
  telephonyService.endCall();
 } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }


}
```

Class--3

```
public interface ITelephony {


  boolean endCall();


  void answerRingingCall();


void silenceRinger();


  void call(String number);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Broadcast Receiver Class seems to be blocking the calls every moment, except for the particular time period.

> Here is an simple approach :-
>
> - From the main-activity get the start time & end time from the user and store it in the **Shared Preferences**.
> - Register your Receiver with `<intent-filter>
>     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
>     </intent-filter>`
> - Inside your Receiver class get the stored values from the **Shared Preferences**, compare it with the current time [As u did in Pervasive_2Activity], If condition is satisfied then end the call(block call) Else do nothing.
>
> Now the Calls will be able to blocked between the desired set time periods.

Answer (score 0):

My view on how to do it:

`1. Create a service
 2. Register the BroadcastReceiver in the Service.
 3. unregister and destroyservice when the specified time expires using a timertask.`

**Creating a service**

Its not complete code just partial code.

```
  public class CallDetectService extends Service {

    BroadcastReceiver PhoneCallReceiver1;

    public CallDetectService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        min = intent.getIntExtra("min", 0);
        hour = intent.getIntExtra("hour", 0);  //get the data from the activity
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
        phonecallReceiver = new PhonecallReceiver(cal.getTimeInMillis(), getApplicationContext());
        registerReceiver(PhoneCallReceiver1 , intentFilter);

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stopSelf();     //if time expires the service will be stopped
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, d);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service destroy called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v("myapp", "stopped the service");
        if (PhoneCallReceiver1 != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(PhoneCallReceiver1 );
            Log.v("myapp", "Unregistered receiver");
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**Calling the Service**

Call the service and pass your from and to time here.

```
final Intent service = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), PhoneCallReceiver1 .class);
 service.putExtra("min", min);
service.putExtra("hour", hour);
getActivity().startService(service);
```

**Add blocking code in receiver**

```
public class PhoneCallReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context = null;
private static final String TAG = "Phone call";
private ITelephony telephonyService;
private Long endtime;
public PhoneCallReceiver1(long time, Context c){
endtime=time;
}
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Receving....");
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  

    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if(endtime<calendar.getTimeInMillis()){
      //you need to block your call, add your logic to block your call.
    }
   catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }

   }
```

Comment: can you tell me that how can i take time from user in a activity and how that time of that activity will be checked by the time get by system time in service....or there is no need to create activity.....

Comment: You have to collect the time duration the service should run from the activity, use timepicker for this. First timepicker should give you the start time and the second timepicker will give you the end time. Convert to millisenconds and pass to service

Comment: i am getting it dificult to understand ur code...what registr method is doing and where i can put my blocking code and how and where i can code my time checker code and how can i call that my blocking code inside time checker code....please can u give me some more code...

Comment: Isnt your blocking already in PhoneCallReceiver1. registerreceiver function will start it for you. I have updated intentfilter code in my answer.

Comment: it is showing error at following line...Multiple markers at this line.....
    phonecallReceiver = new PhonecallReceiver(cal.getTimeInMillis(), getApplicationContext()); .....                                               errors- phonecallReceiver cannot be resolved to a variable...
 - cal cannot be resolved ....                                      it is phonecallreciever or PhoneCallReceiver1.....and where i have to put my time checking code....

Comment: i removed error of cal can not be resolved ...but wat about  phonecallReceiver cannot be resolved to a variable... ...it is PhoneCallReceiver1 or it is some specified object.....and where i have to check time condition...

Comment: Just change it to PhoneCallReceiver1 phonecallReceiver = new PhoneCallReceiver1 (cal.getTimeInMillis(), getApplicationContext());

Comment: still it is giving following error-----                            constructor PhoneCallReceiver1(long, Context) is undefined
 - PhonecallReceiver cannot be resolved to a type
 - phonecallReceiver cannot be resolved to a variable .....and it is giving suggestion like that.....remove argument to match phonecallreceiver1....and create constructer PhoneCallReceiver1(long,context)......so tell me what should i do now.....and also please tell where i have to put my code of time comparision and blocking code...

Comment: Put the blocking and the time comparison logic in PhonecallReceiver1. To do this you need to pass the time to PhonecallReceiver1 and this you can do with creating a public constructor in PhonecallReceiver1. In the PhonecallReceiver1 assign the time to a local variable to do your comparison. I will update my answer to add this.

Comment: ok ..i got that point...now i took from and to time..the duration between i have to block the calls.. i did like this               min=intent.getIntExtra("min", 0);
hour=intent.getIntExtra("hour", 0);                              min1=intent.getIntExtra("min1", 0);
hour1=intent.getIntExtra("hour1", 0);..i took this data as you suggest..how this data is parsing to phonecallrecevier1....and it is showing message that phonecallreceiver local variable never used..i want to compare to and from data with the system time..how can i get above code in phonecallreceiver1..n plz give your mailid..